# Localised Search

Tags: carto

I may have missed this in the documentation, but is it possible to set the search box in CartoDB to localise to a certain country? For example, we have an English userbase so if you search for "Newcastle" you want to end up in the UK, not South Africa. You can do this in Google Maps so I was hoping CartoDB would have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible by configuration or through the editor itself out of the box, but you can achieve it by customizing the search tools yourself through [CartoDB.js](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html). See this gist for an example: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/05e6feec84f12ab362df